# Why is the security level defined by $\log _{2} \inf \{ t_{i}/\varepsilon_{i} \mid i \in I \}$

Tags: provable-security, security-definition

> In public-key cryptography, the security level indicates the strength of an adversary in breaking a scheme or solving a problem, which can be seen as the time cost of breaking a scheme or solving a problem. Generating a scheme with a security parameter $k$ does not mean that this scheme has $k$-bit security. The real security level depends on the mathematical primitive and the scheme construction.

> Suppose all potential attack algorithms to break a proposed scheme have been
> found with the following distinct time cost and advantage

> $$\{ (t_{i},\varepsilon_{i}) \mid i \in I \}$$

> Let

> $$2^{k^*} = \inf \{ t_{i}/\varepsilon_{i} \mid i \in I \}$$

> Then we sat this scheme is $k^*$-bit security.

My question is why the form is $t_{i}/\varepsilon_{i}$?

Of course the security level depends on the time cost $t$ and the advantage $\varepsilon$.
I assume that

$$2^{k^*} = \inf \{ f(t_{i}, \varepsilon_{i}) \mid i \in I \}$$

Thus, there are some basic properties of $f$.

P1. For $t_{2} > t_{1}$ and $\varepsilon_{2} > \varepsilon_{1}$, $f(t_{2}, \varepsilon_{1}) > f(t_{1}, \varepsilon_{1}) > f(t_{1}, \varepsilon_{2})$. If we assume that $f$ is smooth, then we can let $df/dt > 0$ and $df/d\varepsilon < 0$.

P2. For every attack algorithm,  $f(t, \varepsilon) \leq 2^k$.

P1 and P2 hold true if we let $f(t,\varepsilon) = t / \varepsilon$.

However, there are many functions that satisfy these properties. And I think $f$ should also satisfy more properties.

For example, given an attack algorithm $A$, for the trivial modification of $A$, the value of $f$ should be the same.
Let $A_{n}$ be an algotithm that calls $A$ for $n$ times, $A_{n}(x) = 1$ if and only if there are more than $n/2$ times that $A(x) = 1$.
We know that
$$\frac{t_{A_{3}}}{\varepsilon_{A_{3}}} = \frac{3 t_{A}} {3\varepsilon_{A}/2} \neq \frac{t_{A}} {\varepsilon_{A}} $$

I try to explain the "trivial modification" more clearly.
If there is an oracle machine $M$ which is independent of the scheme, then I think $M^{A}$ should be a "trivial modification" of $A$.
I believe that the power of $M^{A}$ should not be stronger than $A$. However, I do not know how to define the oracle machine $M$ in a formal way. So, I give above example of $M$ such that $M$ asks oracle $A$ for $n$ times and the output of $M^{A}$ only depends on these $n$ answers.
We do not care about the specific attack algorithm $A$ is (and whether $A$ has the accesses to some oracles.)

Answer (score 3):

The value $t/\epsilon$ is the expected amount of time required for an attacker to "win". E.g., if he has a 50% $(\epsilon = 0.5)$ probability to guess a key in $t = 10$ seconds, then the expected length of time for him to guess the key is $t/\epsilon = 10s/0.5 = 20s$

The example you provided is a bit unspecified, and it's not clear to me that $A_3$ is a "trivial modification" of $A$, what a "trivial modification" means, or why we would expect a "trivial modification" to retain the security of the original.

To be more concrete consider two examples:

First, a blockcipher $E$ with 128 bits of security (for simplicity, 128-bit keys and 128-bit blocks). Then $E'_{k1,k2}(x) = E_{k1}(E_{k2}(x))$ could be considered a "trivial modification" of $E$ and has, as you say, pretty much the same security level --- in this case, 129 bits due to a meet-in-the-middle attack.

On the other hand, if you view the blockcipher $E$ as a PRF, then the "trivial modification" $E'_{k1,k2}(x) = E_{k1}(x) \oplus E_{k2}(x)$ has significantly more security --- we've gone from ~64 bits of security (generic birthday-bound attack) to ~85 bits of security (c.f "The sum of PRPs is a secure PRF" by Stefan Lucks).

So in the absence of more specific information about your $A_3$, it's entirely reasonable that $A_3$ may have either about the same, significantly more, or even significantly less security than $A$.

**A final note** I don't know what text your definition comes from, but although it's a completely reasonable definition for "bits of security" --- a term often used informally --- it's a bit incomplete since it doesn't account for possible limits to the number of queries an attacker can make, or the amount of pre-computation he could perform before being provided with oracle access.

Comment: The definition is cited from [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319930480) (4.1.12)

Comment: Actually, I do not know what kinds of modification should be "trivial modification". So I just give an example. I do not believe that $f(t, \varepsilon) = t/\varepsilon$ is the best function. So, I want more evidences to show that the value $t/\varepsilon$ makes sense. Your modification is about the encryption algorithm. I do not know how do you compare the security between $E$ and $E'$. It seems that you still consider some attack algorithm $A$ and the value of $t_{A}/\varepsilon_{A}$. My modification is about the attack algorithm itself.

Comment: This is largely a good answer, but beware (a) the use of _time_ as the only cost, because in many cases you can reduce time by running more machines in parallel at the same cost; and (b) the use of single-target attacks as a proxy for the cost of multi-target attacks, when in many cases like a block cipher an attack on $n$ targets simultaneously can be $n$ times cheaper than an attack on one target and about $n^3$ times faster—so to find the first of a billion 128-bit keys for a block cipher the cost is well below $2^{100}$, which is why I advise _against_ saying AES128 gives 128-bit security.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some papers recently suggesting alternative measures of bit security (roughly meaning alternative $f(\cdot)$), at least in indistinguishability games.
The two I know are

- [On the Bit Security of Cryptographic Primitives](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/077) by Micciancio and Walter, and
- [Bit Security as Computational Cost for
  Winning Games with High Probability](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1258.pdf), by Watanabe1 and Yasunaga

Both papers have the same definition in search games, where (at least where it is publicly verifiable if you "found the right thing")

I don't believe they answer your question though, which appears to be trying to pin down the form of $f(\cdot)$ "from first principles".
The motivating factor of the aforementioned papers is really resolving a certain "paradox" regarding notions of bit security for PRGs, I would suggest just reading the intro to the Micciancio Walter paper for details.